# Scraping field using Beautiful soup

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I am new to web scraping. I m not able to fetch a field(username) from the webpage.

This is the HTML of the web page with the field I am interested in.

```html
        <div class="block-body">
          <div class="block-row block-row--separated">
          <div class="block-row block-row--separated">
            <dl class="pairs pairs--columns pairs--fixedSmall">
            <dl class="pairs pairs--columns pairs--fixedSmall">
            <dl class="pairs pairs--columns pairs--fixedSmall">
            <dl class="pairs pairs--columns pairs--fixedSmall">
            <dl class="pairs pairs--columns pairs--fixedSmall">
            <dl class="pairs pairs--columns pairs--fixedSmall">
            <dl class="pairs pairs--columns pairs--fixedSmall">
              <dt>YouTube Username</dt>
                            <dd>



                              GET_THIS_FIELD



                            </dd>
                          </dl>



            <dl class="pairs pairs--columns pairs--fixedSmall">
```

Following are the issues which I'm facing:

1. I am no able to extract the field since there are several objects with the same class, the text option is not working and I have no idea how to find the solution.
2. Since thE field YOUTUBE USERNAME is not present in all the pages I am visiting, I need to include a control.

I tried everything, this is just the last attempt.

```html
        profile_content = profile.content 
        soup2 = BeautifulSoup(profile_content, features="lxml") 
        if soup2.find(text=re.compile('^YouTube Username$')): 
          user_channel = soup2.find("dl", {'class': 'pairs pairs--columns pairs--fixedSmall'}).find_next_siblings('dd')
        else: 
          user_channel = "none"
```

Thank you for your help!

Comment: please [edit] your question and include the `HTML` part as a code instead of `img` so we can manually check and verify.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Asuming the HTML code is correct I could provide this answer:

```
# data is the HTML code as string
soup = BeautifulSoup(data, 'html.parser')

the_field = soup.find('dt', string='YouTube Username').find_next('dd').text.strip()

print(the_field)
```

For your own safety you can add tests if the string was found, etc. Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks a lot, your comment was super helpful as I realized that my HTML was not loaded correctly because of typos in the URL. You made my day!

Comment: Then do me a favour and upvote my answer and mark it as answered. Thank you.

Comment: There should be a grey hook and also two arrows, one up, one down. Klicking on the hook means answer correct and accepted, the arrows are there to up- or downvote the answer.